# Multithreaded Browser

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I have created my own Browser with a `TabControl` and adding multiple instances of the `WebBrowser` control to the respective `TabPages`.

Now what I need to do is perform actions on said `WebBrowser`-controls possibly at the same time and I was gonna use multithreading for this. The problem is, performing actions on GUI-elements needs to be done on the GUI thread, requiring Invokation when using multithreading, which would then be executed on the same thread again.

What can I do about this? Is there any way for me to perform actions on GUI elements at the same time?

Comment: The actions performed on the GUI elements should usually be fast enough to do on one thread. The problem is all the other time consuming tasks. As long aus you make sure to `Invoke` only the UI operations and not the other, more time consuming tasks, you should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not. Since I'm dealing with `WebBrowser`'s, those actions might take their time, since I will be forced to continually wait for elemtents to load into the GUI while navigating to the next page.